# Program for finding factorions in a given range

Tags: python, numpy, loops, factorial

I recently encountered a mathematical object called a "factorion", which is a number  that is equal to the sum of the factorials of its individual digits. For example, 145 is a factorion because 1! + 4! + 5! = 1 + 24 + 120 = 145.

So I decided write some basic Python code in order to find the numbers systematically within a given range. The following is the code I came up with:

```
#factorion finding
from numpy import *
from math import *

def factorion(a, b):
    factorions = []
    for i in range(a, b):
        atom = []
        while i != 0:
            atom.append(i % 10)
            i = i // 10

        sum = 0
        j = 0
        while j < len(atom):
            sum += factorial(atom[j])
            j += 1

        if sum == i:
            factorions.append(i)

    return factorions

factorion(1,1000)
```

Python is not giving me any errors for this but output comes out to be just the empty list [], when I know that at least 145 should be there, and also 1 and 2.

What's the problem here?

Comment: To make your code clear(er) don't use `*` imports.  I don't think you are using any `numpy` functions here.  If `factoral` is from `math`, you should make that clear.  IN any case, you need to step through your code, making sure each expression is producing the expected result.  That's what I'd have to do to help you.

Comment: Are you sure that there IS such an object? From what I know, finding a factors of a general number is NP-hard problem, and I doubt that there is some object which does it in `NumPy`, or in `math` modules. Of course, I may be wrong, so please provide a documentation of this module. Also, in your code you use `factorial` not `factorion`, which is just the `x!`.

Comment: you try to update range variable `i` inside the loop it dosn't work

Answer (score 1):

You are changing that 'i' loop index inside the loop.

There must be a more pythonic way of turning a number into a list of its digits without changing the number iteself, like:

```
digits = [int(s) for s in str(number)]
```

Comment: Yes, and perhaps the entire body of the loop can be shortened like this: `if sum(math.factorial(int(d)) for d in str(i)) == i: factorions.append(i)`